# Sharepoint Lookup Lists

Tags: sharepoint, vlookup

I have two sharepoint lists - A & B for the sake of the question.

List A contains a formulated comulm (X) which provides a text value based on entries in two other columns.

List B contains a look up column (Y) to list A which provides the user with all available values in column X.

I am trying, but can't figure out (quite new to sharepoint in general) how to hid any values from column X that have been used in column Y.

I tried to do research on it but can't seem to find an answer that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lookup column, there is no OOB ways to hide the values in the drop down. You may need to use JS code to achieve this.